# Form Action to edit database

Tags: php, forms, submit

I tried reading all the other topics on this, but nothing was too close to what I need. So, if I missed something somewhere, sorry, but for now, I'm having a common issue and can't find a solution.

I made a form that connects to my database to edit news articles that I have posted. Everything is working fine when it comes to functionality and getting the data, but my issue is really trying to submit my edit.

This is the form itself:

```
<form method="get" action="/index.php?page=editnews&id=$row[id]">
  <div><label>id</label><input type="text" name="id" id="id" value="<?= $row['id']?>" readonly/></div>
  <div><label>Header</label><input type="text" name="header" id="header" value="<?= $row['header']?>"/></div>
  <div><label>Story</label><textarea type="text" name="story" id="story" cols="10" rows="20" wrap="soft"><?= $row['story']?></textarea></div>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

When I hit submit, it only takes me to "index.php=id". It's skipping the whole "page=editnews" part after index.php.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Also, since you already have the `id` as a form field, why would you need to pass it in the URL as well? Just add the page as a hidden input and you'll be fine.

Comment: This did work. Thank you very much for that. I saw that during one of my searches, but didn't think it would apply to my situation. So thank you very much for this =D The reason I'm passing it in the URL is so it just redirects back to the edit page of the specific article I was editing.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the below

```
<form method="get" action="/index.php?page=editnews&id=$row[id]">
```

with

```
<form method="get" action="/index.php?page=editnews&id=<?php echo $row[id]; ?>">
```

Comment: I still seem to be having the issue, but I also just found another. My header text box isn't showing and that's probably where my issue is. Once I figure that out, I'll let you know what happens.

Comment: Yeah, it's still omitting "?page=editnews&" when I hit submit.